# About Unused functions in VC++

Tags: c, visual-c++

Just wanted to verify that in VC++, unused member functions which are never called are by default considered as inlined functions by the compiler? If so why it is so, why not completely discard (since it will never be called) this function instead of in-lining it?

What is the advantage?

Update 
The question is why even inline it when it will never be called? Why not simply discard it forever, just like some unused variables are discarded.

Comment: Why would they be considered inline if they aren't ever used??

Comment: So you mean my understanding "unused member functions which are never called are by default considered as inlined functions by the compiler" is wrong?

Comment: where's that quote from?

Comment: It's called link time optimization. Yes unused symbols and even objects can be discarded _in some circumstances_. But I don't think any standard mandates anything in this regard. All of this has zarroo to do with inlining

Comment: @Tony somebody is arguing with me, it is his words not mine ...

Comment: @gpuguy: You're the one who asked the question, they're your words.

Comment: @gpuguy link to the argument? Or is it IRL?

Comment: @gpuguy: If they're somebody else's words, invite that somebody over here. :-P

Answer (score 1):

Member functions are considered inline without use of the `inline` keyword if they are defined in the body of the class definition. Whether they are called or not has nothing to do with it.

Unused member functions can't generally be discarded because their names have external linkage -- that is to say, some other translation unit or executable might call them, that hasn't even been written at the time this translation unit is compiled or this executable is linked.

Once you get to link-time, if the implementation somehow knows that this cannot happen then it could discard the code for the function. For example because the OS has no means to look up symbols in an executable, or because you've told the linker to strip them out using some implementation-defined option.

Relating this to VC++ in particular: on Windows you can look up symbols in executables if they're `dllexport`. So those functions won't generally be discarded even at link time, and other unused functions can't be discarded at compile time just because this TU doesn't use it. For *most* classes defined in the usual way, with a header file that declares the member functions and a source file that defines them, the functions are unused in that source file. So if the compiler discarded them because they were unused in that TU, nothing would ever work.

I *think* (I'm not sure) that whether the function is inline or not is relevant to whether it can be discarded, but might not mean that it can be entirely discarded. It's true that if it's inline, and someone calls it, then that someone must have the definition of the function in their TU. So in some sense the function is "not needed". However, any `static` local variables must be shared no matter what TU it's called from, and the address of the function itself must be the same no matter what TU it's taken in. So there may still have to be "something" there even if it's not the full code for the function.

But as I said -- even if inline functions can be discarded when unused, not all unused functions are inline.

Answer (score 0):

Inline it where? It's never called, so it's impossible to inline it into any call site.

The Standard mandates whether a function is or is not considered inline. Whether or not it is called is irrelevant.

Comment: I think standard doesn't **mandate** inline or not, it is just a hint for compilers, right?

Comment: @lzprgmr: wrong. The standard mandates whether a function "is inline" or not. It doesn't mandate whether a function "gets inlined" into a particular call site or not, but that optimization hint is the secondary, less-important meaning of inline. The main meaning (that the function can be defined in multiple TUs without violating the One Definition Rule, and that the definition must be present in every TU that the function is called from) is not a hint, it's required.